# Flight to Moscow on March 15th, do I need to expedite my Russian visa request?

Tags: visas, russia, tourist-visas, applications

Looks like I have all my documents in line, and I can mail them off tomorrow morning - March 1st.

They will arrive at the Russian Consulate in Houston on the 2nd with overnight delivery.

This is my first time getting a Russian visa or visiting Russia (very excited), and the application is straightforward and I'm financially secure.  Question is simply, what is your experience as far as timeline for the Visa to arrive, and at what point should I actually go to the consulate if that proves necessary?  I may be over-concerned, and hopefully the Visa arrives before 2 weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Houston center of the visa processing service used by the consulate states on [this page](http://ils-usa.com/page/65?domain=5&language=10):

> **Visa Processing Times**
>
> The Russian Embassy or Consulate General reviews your visa application
>   and decides whether to issue you a visa within a period of **4 to 10**
>   **calendar days**, after having received all the necessary documents and
>   received payment in full.
>
> In extreme emergencies which require urgent passage to the Russian
>   Federation, the applicant may petition the Consulate to review his
>   materials in an expedited manner, thus reducing the processing time
>   substantially to 3 business days or less. In such situations, the
>   decision to issue an emergency visa is made either by the Russian
>   Ministry of Foreign Affairs, the Federal Migration Service of the
>   Russian Federation, and either the Ambassador or the Consul General of
>   the Russian Federation.
>
> Likewise, in special circumstances the consulate has the right to
>   review submitted documents for up to 30 days.